# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found when importing keras

Tags: python, keras

When I run

> from keras.preprocessing import image

it shows the error as below.

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from keras.preprocessing import image
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 10, i
n <module>
    from scipy import linalg
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 175, in <
module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module
>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Python352\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <modu
le>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I failed to install keras using `pip install keras`. So I download scipy and keras whl from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) and install it. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: The last line of error says that the '_fblas' module was not found followed by a message about a DLL load failed. This suggests that '_flbas' module is a native code. Try  to find in your filesystem the file '_fblas.dll'  and add it to the path of your PYTHONPATH environment variable before executing the script.

Comment: I'm happy to know that Gohlke now has theano, tensorflow and keras! I wonder if they will run faster than the terrible `pip install` ones....

Comment: Maybe you should try to get everthining from that site. Remove keras, tensorflow, scipy and numpy, and reinstall them all from this site in this order: numpy, scipy, tensorflow, keras

Comment: I tried here, and got disappointed. Golkhe's tensorflow + keras didn't work for me. Only `pip install tensorflow` and `pip install keras` worked.

Comment: What worked for me was: 1 - numpy from Gohlke; 2 - scipy from Gohlke; 3 - tensorflow from pip; 4 keras from pip

Answer (score 1):

Better install Anaconda (**roughly speaking** a python with alot of prebuilt packages Windows-ready) https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows.html

then `pip install -U tensorflow tensorflow-gpu keras`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. My problem was solved when I uninstalled the current tensorflow version and installed tensorflow==2.0.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```